# How to pass sysdate-1 from dual into grep

Tags: shell

I am having a.log which contains log of a week from Sunday to Saturday .if I ran the script today then it should search for yesterday

I am doing

```
Date = `print " set heading off
  set feedback off
  set pagesize 0
  select to_char(sysdate-1, 'DD Mon')" | Sqlplus`
print "Date = $Date"

grep .Ccd /var/tmp/logs/poll.log | grep "$date"
```

But I am not able to fetch sysdate-1

Comment: Please clarify "I am not able to fetch...". What happens when you try?

Comment: What shell is this?

Comment: @glennjackman ksh

Comment: In a variable assignment, you **cannot** put spaces around `=`. You are not setting a variable, you are attempting to execute the `Date` command with `=` as the first argument and the output of your Sqlplus command as the rest of the arguments. Bruce has the right answer below.

Comment: @glennjackman yes I removed but still not working

Comment: Update your question, and show us exactly what Date contains: `echo ">>>$Date<<<"`

Comment: Also, do you really have a command named `Sqlplus` (with a capital S)?

Comment: @glennjackman I am having a log file poll.log which looks like

Comment: Nov 14 17:01 SA48001.Ccd . logs contain this .Ccd file for one week . this script will look for the .Ccd files name in the log file for previous day

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can pipe things like that, especially with something as finicky and weird as `sqlplus`.  Here's how I would do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=oracle
PASSWORD=adminadmin
INSTANCE=tiger1p

DATE=$(sqlplus -s /nolog << END_SQL
connect $USER/$PASSWORD@$INSTANCE
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set head off
set pagesize 0
select to_char(sysdate-1, 'DD Mon') from dual;
END_SQL
)
grep Ccd /var/tmp/logs/poll.log | grep "$DATE"
```

The SQL for getting "sysdate - 1" resides in a "here" document, but gets put into the shell variable named `DATE`.  I have a superstition about turning off all the `sqlplus` settings, your mileage may vary.

Comment: It's not working .. Not able to grep

Comment: @Pooja - I just copied the "grep" line from your example. I don't know if that's really what you want or not. The "CcD" pattern in particular looked weird. You should probably just start out grepping for "$DATE" and then refine the output from that.

Comment: In $date its not coming sysdate - 1 @Bruce

Comment: @Pooja - just run the `sqlplus` command standalone to see if it gives back what you want. Also note that Linux shell script is case sensitive: "date" and "DATE" name two different values, probably. Also notice that you will have to put in user ID, password and Oracle instance. You can't use my fake values.

Comment: yes I understood , the problem is the SQL fetching as NOV 17 where in logs it is Nov 17 . I am unable to convert the date format